image_dataset_from_directory returning list instead of Dataset object
I am writing a conversion function that utilises the image_dataset_from_directory function from the Keras API. In the documentation, it has listed that the return value is a tf.data.Dataset object type but when printing the type, it returns as a list type.
While using the as_numpy_iterator() function, it throws the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'as_numpy_iterator', when it should be converting the Dataset object to a numpy array. I have since made sure that the conditions are met for the as_numpy_iterator() to run, which are TensorFlow needing to run in eager mode (enabled by default in all 2.x versions) and the dataset's element spec to be TensorSpec (which it is). I found a GitHub issues page that stated something similar but that went unresolved.
Below is the function and the parameters I defined (I am using a certain biased number of images to test my model and do not want to split it into subdirectories just yet, hence the NoneType for the labels and label_mode parameters):
img_gen = img_utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        directory,
        labels=None,
        label_mode=None,
        shuffle=True,
        seed=123,
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="both",
        interpolation="bilinear",
        data_format=None,
        verbose=True,
    )


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The image_dataset_from_directory function returns a tf.data.Dataset object
when the labels parameter is set to 'inferred'. In the code, however, the
value used for labels is None.Please refer to image_dataset_from_directory
